# can't boot after upgrading kernel to 2.6.38-9

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Just upgraded to 2.6.38-9 on Ubuntu 11.04 and rebooted immediately after. It gets as far as the ubuntu logo on the purple screen, then after a moment switches to a black screen with boot status output. The last line is always:

```
* Checking battery state...
```

Followed by a blinking cursor. It hangs there forever. The few lines before it vary, but it always stops at checking battery state. I can access the ctrl-alt-f2 console. What can I do?

edit: solved, problem was I had the wrong nvidia driver enabled - I had version 173, when I should have had the current version.

Comment: If you hold the `SHIFT` key while your computer starts, before the purple Ubuntu loading screen appears, a menu will appear that will let you select an older version of the kernel to start instead.  Does that allow Ubuntu to start properly?

Comment: Yes, it does boot with 2.6.38-8.